# bash: Unable to get one-liner with stderr redirect and || operator to work

Tags: bash, redirect, stderr

I've got the following code which always exits, regardless of success of first command

```
git pull $newURL $branch 2>/dev/null || echo "Unable to connect to git repository @ $gitURL" && exit 1
```

What am I doing wrong?
I can, of course, split it into an if using:

```
if [ $? == 0 ]
```

but I like the neater version.

Comment: you want to exit on success or failure ?

Comment: You're using a combination of `||` and `&&` when you should be using a proper `if` statement.

Comment: `if git pull ...; then echo ...; exit 1; fi`. (Do you really want to exit *only* if `echo` succeeds?)

Comment: @Ôrel wanting to exit on failure of git command, with the echo preceeding the exit.

Comment: @chepner thanks, had mentioned that in my question, but wanted ideally a one-liner

Comment: What's your definition of "one-liner"? Because an `if` statement fits on a single line just as well as a command list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to exit in the "else" error condition, group those two commands together:

```sh
git pull "$newURL" "$branch" 2>/dev/null || { echo "Unable to connect to git repository @ $gitURL" && exit 1; }
                                    here ---/ ..............................................................\--- and here
```

The semicolon is required, to end the list of commands inside the braces.